# Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

This used to be working perfectly until a couple of days back exactly 4 days back. When i run `gcloud app deploy` now it complete the build and then straight after completing the build it hangs on Updating Service

Here is the output:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/just-sleek/regions/us-central1/operations/8260bef8-b882-4313-bf97-efff8d603c5f error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-05-26T05:20:44.032Z4316.jc.11: Deployment Manager operation just-sleek/operation-1590470444486-5a68641de8da1-5dfcfe5c-b041c398 errors: [
code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-20200526t070946/resources/aef-default-20200526t070946"
message: {
\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",
\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",
\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{
\"code\":403,
\"errors\":[{
\"domain\":\"usageLimits\",
\"message\":\"Exceeded limit \'QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES\' on resource \'aef-default-20200526t070946\'. Limit: 8.0\",
\"reason\":\"limitExceeded\"
}],
\"message\":\"Exceeded limit \'QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES\' on resource \'aef-default-20200526t070946\'. Limit: 8.0\",
\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",
\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/just-sleek/regions/us-central1/autoscalers\",
\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"
}
}"]
```

I tried the following the ways to resolve the error:

- I deleted all my previous version and left the running version
- I ran `gcloud components update` still fails.
- I create a new project, changed the region from [REGION1] to [REGION2] and deployed and m still getting the same error.
- Also ran `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug`, does not give me any different result

I have no clue what is causing this issue and how to solve it please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Google is already aware of this issue and it is currently being investigated.

There is a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/157161938), you may 'star' and follow so that you can receive any further updates on this. In addition, you may see some workarounds posted that could be performed temporarily if agreed with your preferences.

Currently, there is no ETA yet for the resolution but there will be an update provided as soon as the team progresses on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding this into my app.yaml

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 7
```

I found the solution here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157449521

And I was also redirected to:

[gcloud app deploy - updating service default fails with code 13 Quota for instances limit exceeded, and 401 unathorizeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845193/gcloud-app-deploy-updating-service-default-fails-with-code-13-quota-for-instan)